# $? = mc^{1.9}$ makes me crazy

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

If energy equals mass times the speed of light squared, what is mass times just under the speed of light? It's not energy,,,yet.

Michio Kaku said in a physics video that the faster mass goes, the heavier it gets. I'm not understanding how acceleration can both convert mass to energy and render it heavier.

I am a total physics noob, but planned to write some fiction in the future with physics as a backdrop. To that end, I began to watch learning physics videos on YouTube. This thing woke me up in the middle of the night, and it's been driving me crazy ever since. I might rethink the topic of my next novel based on how ignorant I remain on the subject.

Comment: Decreasing the velocity would not decrease the *power* to which $c$ is raised.

Comment: Also, $mc^{1.9}$ does not even have units of energy.

Comment: You must mean M*(.9C)^2  which still has units of energy.

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at the derivation of the formula before you let it drive you crazy :-)

Comment: The OP clearly hasn't a clear idea of what energy is, so I don't think it's useful to try to explain the relativistic point of view on energy. Susan, I suggest 2 possibilities: 1) Picking another topic for your next novel. 2) Learn up to that point in physics in a rigorous manner. (The problem with option 2 is that once you start learning, you'll end up wanting to become a physicist :D).

Comment: This is a weird question. The question has -4, but 3 favourites and my answer with +4 :S

Comment: Yeah, this question doesn't fall neatly into any known category, so some think it doesn't belong here, while others differ.

Comment: >> *I am a total physics noob,... but I began to watch learning physics videos on YouTube. Michio Kaku said...* << Yeah sure when you learn physics from Youtube you should start with https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics or https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=yalecourses+shankar or https://www.youtube.com/user/StanfordUniversity/playlists or something reasonable but surely not Michiu Kako and collegues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the velocity is slower than the speed of light (which is always the case) the newtonian limit for small velocities is

$$E_{kinetic}=\frac{m\cdot v^2}{2}$$

and in relativity

$$E_{kinetic}=\frac{m\cdot c^2}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}-m\cdot c^2$$

The rest energy is always

$$m\cdot c^2$$

no matter what the velocity is.

Answer (score 4):

One of the insights of special relativity is that space and time are not absolute or distinct; instead of thinking of space and time, we should think of space-time. One consequence is that we should, in principle, measure space and time with the same unit. We haven't done that; we've measured time in seconds and space (distance) in metres.

The factor of $c^2$ in $E=mc^2$ is there only to fix our naive system of units. A more natural way of writing the equation is 
$$
E = m,
$$
the $c^2$ has no physical implications, it stems from a convention to measure space and time in different units. The equation implies that the energy of an object at rest is equal to its mass. (Note however that the equation follows from special relativity and not from dimensional analysis)

I now come to your question about mass. I don't think Kaku's explanation that if an object is travelling faster, it is more massive is particularly helpful. Instead, let's say that an object's (rest) mass is independent of that object's velocity, but that its energy increases as its velocity increases.

Comment: I think that is slightly misleading. It seems like you're saying that in units where $c=1$, $E=m$ is a tautology due to dimensional analysis. *A priori*, there is no way to know that rest mass energy is even a thing.

Comment: ok, maybe there are other people who will be left with that impression, so i've tried to stress that that's not the case.

Comment: I'm just worried about OP getting the wrong impression. I've seen plenty of YouTube and Reddit comments saying $E=mc^2$ is trivial dimensional analysis. Thank you for your edit.